# What is the intuitive idea behind looking for a solution of the form an=r^n for a linear homogeneous recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

In my textbook, under solving linear homogeneous recurrence relations, it says that the basic approach for solving them is to look for a solution of the form a<sub>n</sub> = r<sup>n</sup>, which yields the characteristic equation. Then there is a proof that the solution of a linear homogeneous recurrence relation of degree 2 with 2 distinct roots is a<sub>n</sub> = α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> + α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup>. After looking at the proof I understand why this is so. What I don't understand is the more intuitive idea behind it. Why in the the first place do we start looking for a solution of the form r<sup>n</sup>? For such an equation of degree 1 where  a<sub>n</sub> = c*a<sub>n-1</sub>, if you start to express the terms as the previous:

a<sub>1</sub> = c*a<sub>0</sub>,   a<sub>2</sub>=c*a<sub>1</sub>=c*c*a<sub>0</sub>,   ... 
a<sub>n</sub>=c*a<sub>n-1</sub>=c<sup>n</sup> * a<sub>0</sub>,
   you can clearly see that the solution is of form a<sub>n</sub> = α*r<sup>n</sup>. 
Is there a similar way of looking at a solution of an equation of a higher degree. Also I understand that when you substitute a<sub>n</sub> = α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> + α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup> into c<sub>1</sub>*a<sub>n-1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>*a<sub>n-2</sub> = a<sub>n</sub> and you do a little math you prove that the solution satisfies the equation, but why in the first place assume that a<sub>n</sub> = α<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> + α<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>n</sup> would satisfy the equation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear homogeneous recurrence relations with repeated roots; motivation behind looking for solutions of the form $nx^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129849/linear-homogeneous-recurrence-relations-with-repeated-roots-motivation-behind-l)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer 1**: we know that exponentials satisfy linear recurrences. So we try to fit the linear recurrence to an exponential. We check the result to justify our work a posteriori.

**Short answer 2**: someone has worked this method out in the past, so we use it.

**Medium answer**: we can write a linear recurrence relation as a matrix equation

$$ v_{n+1} = A v_n $$

where $v_n$ is a vector whose components are consecutive terms of the linear recurrence. This is easy to solve:

$$ v_n = A^n v_0 $$

If $A$ is diagonalizable, we can obtain a closed form for $v_n$ by diagonalizing and computing the exponential.

**Long answer**: there is a theory of *difference equations* that is quite analogous to the theory of differential equations. Given a function $f$, we define the (forward) difference $\Delta f$ to be the function $(\Delta f)(n) = f(n+1) - f(n)$. Many things in the theory of differential calculus have analogs in this difference calculus.

For example, the analog of the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\Delta f)(i) = f(n) - f(0) $$

As in calculus, we learn differences of all sorts of functions. Some are nice:

$$ \Delta(a^n) = (a-1) a^n $$

and some are less nice:

$$ \Delta(x^3) = 3x^2 + 3x + 1 $$

actually, we usually use falling factorials instead of powers of $x$: we define

$$ x^{\underline{n}} = x (x-1) (x-2) \ldots (x-(n-1)) $$

and we have

$$ \Delta(x^{\underline{n}}) = n x^{\underline{n-1}} $$

A linear recurrence can be written as an ordinary difference equation.

Define the forward translation operator $(Ef)(n) = f(n+1)$; or as difference operators $E = \Delta + 1$. Consider the Fibonacci numbers as an example:

$$ f(n+2) = f(n) + f(n+1) $$

can be rewritten as

$$ E^2 f = f + E f $$

which we can solve in an analogous way to how we derive the solution to the analogous differential equation. e.g. we might rewrite it and factor:

$$ (E^2 - E - 1)f = 0 $$
$$ (E - r_1)(E - r_2) f = 0 $$

and solve the difference equation in steps.

(we could rewrite this in terms of $\Delta$ by substituting $E = \Delta + 1$, but leaving it in terms of $E$ is fine too)

Of course, we don't actually do that: like with differential equations, we get introduced to a few recipes for handling common equations, and simply *memorize* the solution technique. Or if we didn't have it memorized, we might use the guess and check recipe, knowing that the analogous differential equation has its solution as a linear combination of exponentials. (and that exponentials in differential equations are analogous to exponentials in difference equations)

Comment: Hi! I had the same question as the OP, and this is the clearest answer I've been able to find anywhere on the Internet so far. I find that I still don't quite understand how we can go from seeing $(E^2 - E - 1)f = 0$ to $(E - r_1)(E - r_2)f = 0$ -- where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the polynomial, I assume.

Comment: @Eli: The distributive law still applies, because we're working with *linear* operators: $(E-a)(E-b)$ is the same operator as $E^2 - aE - Eb + ab$. Since $b$ is a scalar, $Eb = bE$, so we have $(E-a)(E-b) = E^2 - (a+b)E + ab$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that $1$ was the identity operator in this case. Okay, I now understand how to pass from the first equation to the second. But I don't think I understand "solve the difference equation in steps". How do we get an explicit formula for $f(n)$ from $(E - r_1)(E - r_2)f = 0$?

Comment: @Eli: You find the complete space of solutions to $(E-r_1)g = 0$, then you solve $(E - r_2)f = g$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a_{n+1}=ra_n-sa_{n-1}$ and that $p,q$ are the roots of $x^2-rx+s=0$ so that $r=p+q$ and $s=pq$

Then $$a_{n+1}-(p+q)a_n+pqa_{n-1}=(a_{n+1}-pa_n)-q(a_n-pa_{n-1})=0$$

**If we let $b_n=a_{n+1}-pa_n$ then $b_n=qa_{n-1}=Bq^n$

We can split the recurrence the other way (swap $p$ and $q$) to obtain $c_n=a_{n+1}-qa_n=Cp^n$

Then $$b_n-c_n=(q-p)a_n=Bq^n-Cp^n$$

For me the ** comment above is the one which most feeds my intuition about this problem.

---

Quite another way around is to notice that if $p,q$ are the roots of $x^2-rx+s=0$ then they are also roots of $Ax^{n+2}-Arx^{n+1}+Asx^n=0$ so that if we have $a_n=Ap^n+Bq^n$ we can add $$(Ap^{n+2}-Arp^{n+1}+Asp^n)+(Bq^{n+2}-Brq^{n+1}+Bsq^n)=0+0=0$$ to obtain $$a_{n+2}-ra_{n+1}+sa_n=0$$

So the recurrence comes from studying the roots of the quadratic equation